# Como llamar un metodo public desde otro método static

Tags: android

En mi programa quiero llamar desde un método static MyPreferenceFragment un método public getSettingUSB, pero como el compilador me da error al cambiar este método public a static, aparentemente la llamada es aceptada....

Aquí están mi códigos stactic:

```
public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_setup_com);

        setHasOptionsMenu( true );
    .
    .
    getSettingUSB();
    }
```

Aquí están mi códigos public:

```
    public void getSettingUSB(){
        TwoStatePreference SPconfigenableeco2 = (TwoStatePreference) 
        findPreference("config_enable_eco");
        Boolean mconfigenableecoX = SPconfigenableeco2.isChecked();
    }
```

pero me da error con la función findPreference, alguien me puede decir como resolver esto.

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente define como static el método a llamar:

```
public static void getSettingUSB(){
        TwoStatePreference SPconfigenableeco2 = (TwoStatePreference) 
        findPreference("config_enable_eco");
        Boolean mconfigenableecoX = SPconfigenableeco2.isChecked();
    }
```

Comment: Si, ya lo hice pero al hacer esto ahora tengo problemas con el findPreference, por que no es un método static